# Pinescript DC resolution

Tags: pine-script

I want to plot a donchian channel from a higher timeframe on my current timeframe.  I do get it to work but the plotting seems to stop where the previous candle of the higher timeframe ended.

What I mean is that if the higher timeframe 240 is the one I want to plot on the 1hr graph and we are at 3.35 of the 4hr candle being printed, the indicator will only print to the last 4hr.  So I will not see any plot on my current chart for the 3 and half candles until the 4hr finish the lastest print.

Comment: Need More clarification on this, can you please add more details ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `security()` function to access higher TFs.

```
//@version=4
study(title="Donchian Channels", shorttitle="DC", overlay=true)
length = input(20, minval=1)
lower = lowest(length)
upper = highest(length)
basis = avg(upper, lower)

u = security(syminfo.tickerid, "240", upper)
l = security(syminfo.tickerid, "240", lower)

plot(u)
plot(l)
```

Comment: This is amazing thank you Edward. Thank you for your help.  If I also want to add an alert for when the price comes within range of the upper or lower band is there a way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "when the price comes within range"? The price will never exceed the channel. (PS don't forget to upvote and mark the answer as accepted)

Comment: If I have the price coming towards the 4hr upper band the bands can get a touch from candle.  Then price either break back down or continue higher up and eventually push the upper band to point upwards?

Comment: For that you need one candle for confirmation, so you will know the price will not continue climbing, add this to the script `pullback = u == u[1] and u[1] > u[2]` and plot it to see how it works and the alert `alertcondition(pullback, "text", "text")`

Comment: Hi mate.  Thank you for this.  What I was wondering is if I get the value of the u which is 1.4567 for argument sake ( I have noticed that being the case under the data module) is there not just a way to check the close price and the minute it is within 10 points of the value of the u (upper) value then it triggers the alert?  Dont know if that is possible?  Again thank you so much for the help.  It is much appreciated.

Comment: Hi mate.  Is there any chance you can help me with another question?